# How do I disable the password recovery link?

Tags: 8

How can I disable, in the standard login form, the link for password recovery? I need it for my custom theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.2.x).

E.g.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  if($route_name == 'user.login') {
    $data['tabs'][0]['user.pass']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure to replace MY_MODULE with the actual name of your module.

Comment: It is not working. First a put it into myTheme.theme file and than I tried myModule.module file. But no chance. I still see the password recovery link

Comment: I actually tested the above code so I know it works. This code should sit in a custom module. Make sure custom modules have info files and are enabled. You will also need to clear the cache before you'll be able to see the change.

Comment: Not working. Drupal 9.4.8. Code is placed in module, cache cleared and it's executed. $data is there. Tried also unsetting whole $data['tabs'][0]['user.pass'], but link is still on login page.

Answer (score 3):

For non-programmers, try [No Request New Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/noreqnewpass) module